# How to use Loader on async multiple request in Redux and React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set Loader when data is not fetched yet. This scenario would be easy if the data would be uploaded only ones (logic here: set a flag is isFetching to true, when receiving from redux set it to false). But my scenario is a bit different. I'd like to get my data multiple times to update my Calendar component. All is done thru redux with axios package.

It looks like that:

My reducer adds isFetching flag when my axios request is done(the store is updated):

```
import { ACTIVE_MONTH } from "../actions/types";

export default function(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ACTIVE_MONTH:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching: false,
                fullyBooked: action.payload
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the component looks like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import ChooseHour from './ChooseHour';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Calendario extends Component {
    state = { showHours: false, disabledDates: null}

    componentDidMount() {
        const { chosenRoom } = this.props;
        const date = new Date();
        const reqMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const reqYear = date.getFullYear();
        this.props.activeMonthYearToPass({reqMonth, reqYear, chosenRoom});
    }

    onChange = date => this.setState({ date }, () => {
            const { chosenRoom, isBirthday } = this.props;
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            const day = date.getDate();
            const fullDate = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
            const roomAndDayObj = {fullDate, chosenRoom, isBirthday};
            this.props.sendRoomAndDay(roomAndDayObj); 
        }
    );

    onClickDay(e) {
        const { chosenRoom } = this.props;
        !chosenRoom ? this.setState({ errorMsg: "Wybierz pokój", showHours: false}) :
        this.setState({ showHours: true, errorMsg:'' });
    } 

    passActiveDate(activeDate) {
        const { chosenRoom } = this.props;
        const reqMonth = activeDate.getMonth() + 1;
        const reqYear = activeDate.getFullYear();
        this.setState({ pending: true},
            () => this.props.activeMonthYearToPass({reqMonth, reqYear, chosenRoom})
        );
        this.props.passDateDetails({reqMonth, reqYear});
    }

    render() { 
        const { fullyBookedDays, isBirthday } = this.props;
        const { errorMsg, pending } = this.state;
        return ( 
        <div>
            <div className="calendarsCont">
                    <Calendar
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        onClickDay={(e) => this.onClickDay(e)}
                        onActiveDateChange={({ activeStartDate }) => this.passActiveDate(activeStartDate)}
                        value={this.state.date}
                        locale="pl-PL"
                        tileDisabled={({date, view}) =>
                            (view === 'month') && 
                            fullyBookedDays && fullyBookedDays.fullyBooked.some(item =>
                            date.getFullYear() === new Date(item).getFullYear() &&
                            date.getMonth() === new Date(item).getMonth() -1 &&
                            date.getDate() === new Date(item).getDate()
                            )}
                    /> 
                }
            </div> 
            <p style={{color: 'red'}}>{errorMsg}</p>
            <div>
                {this.state.showHours ? 
                    <ChooseHour chosenDay={this.state.date} chosenRoom={this.props.chosenRoom} isBirthday={isBirthday}/> : 
                null}
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({fullyBookedDays}){
    return {
        fullyBookedDays,
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, actions)(Calendario);
```

So the new values will come many times from axios request. 
What kind of strategy do you use in that case?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is multiple fetching requests, or even multiple actions that indicates something async is happening and needs to be stored in a part of the state, I use a counter :

```
export default function(state = {fetchCount: 0}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCHING_THING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                fetchCount: state.fetchCount + 1
            })
        case FETCHING_THING_DONE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                fetchCount: state.fetchCount - 1,
                fullyBooked: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then you can just check `fetchCount > 0` in your mapstatetoprops.

```
function mapStateToProps({fullyBookedDays, fetchCount}){
    return {
        fullyBookedDays,
        isLoading: fetchCount > 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please take below as an example , Redux-thunk style action is used for wrap multiple axios requests and dispatch them all.

```js
//axios call2
function getData1() {
  return axios.get('/data1');
}

//axios call2
function getData2() {
  return axios.get('/data2');
}

//redux-thunk action creator
function getFullData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.all([getData1(), getData2()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    //call normal action creator
    dispatch(fetchData1())
    dispatch(fetchData2())
  }));
   
  };
}

//normal actioncreator
function fetchData1(data)
{
  return {type: "FETCH_DATA1", payload: data}
}

//normal actioncreator
function fetchData2(data)
{
  return {type: "FETCH_DATA2", payload: data}
}



//reducer1:
function reducer1 (state = defaultedState ,action){
return Object.assign({},{...state, data: action.payload,  isFetching: false} )
}

//reducer2:
function reducer2 (state = defaultedState ,action){
  return Object.assign({},{...state, data: action.payload,  isFetching: false} )
}

//component:
mapStateToProps = function(state){
   return {
     data1: state.data1.data,
     data2: state.data2.data,
     isFetching1: state.data1.isFetching,
     isFetching2: state.data2.isFetching
   }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
class MyComponent extends Component{
render(){
    return (!data1 && isFetching1) || (!data2 && isFetching2) ? <Loading> : <DataComponent>

}
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: OP already uses this technique, this doesn't work with multiple requests, because when one will finish it will turn the isFetching flag to false while the second request is still running

Comment: Why don't you wrap these axios requests in the redux-thunk actionCreator where multiple requests can be combined with axios.all and just prepare only one flag(isFetching) for all of the requests(do it in the reducer)

Comment: It's not necessarily the same action that triggers the 2 requests. If 2 separate actions trigger a different axios request your component still needs to know something is still fetching. For example, I use a component when I can add and remove attachments at will. Each will trigger an action that runs an axios request. If user spam clicks the add button, I can't use axios.all, neither can I use a boolean in my state

Comment: Although your actions are dispatched from different components,In this case, yes , axios.all is no way helpful.However,  you can still combine the isFetching flag of those actions together by using isFetching1 || isFetching2 in the render function of your component where you're gonna show some markups.

Comment: Hmm, first of all, I don't like storing fetching1 and fetching2 in my state when all I care about is "is something fetching". Then, how would you handle the case where getFullData() is fired twice before the first one has finished ?